# location.reload() before switching img src with .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reload the page before switching images inside a `.click` function like so...

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function() { 
  location.reload();
  $('#mainImage').attr('src', this.src);
});
```

I have html with one fullsize image and several thumbnails, and the click function works to switch the `src` attribute, but I need a fresh reload each time as well. Anyone know how I could achieve this and keep the img attributes or reload the page before switching the `src` attribute?

Comment: you can't do it that way. You have to use cookies or PHP or anything to store the event so you can reproduce the src switch once the page is reloaded...

Answer (score 1):

As @LekisS pointed out, that's not possible: `reload` prevents you from reliably doing anything else after you call it.

Comment: is there a way to reload afterwards and keep the image src that was replaced?

Comment: as I said: Cookies or server-side scripting (php, asp, anything) along with an AJAX request